# PatternSyntaxException

Tags: java, regex, patternsyntaxexception

Following String causes `PatternSyntaxException`:

```
Pattern.compile("*\\.*");
```

I want to create a pattern so that I can filter all files with the name in the following form: `"*.*"`

How can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To match all strings with a `.` in the name, you do:

```
Pattern.compile(".*[.].*");
```

To break it down:

- `.*` match any number of arbitrary character
- `[.]` match a dot. (yes, `\\.` works too)
- `.*` match any number of arbitrary character

Demo:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(".*[.].*");

System.out.println(p.matcher("hello.txt").matches()); // true
System.out.println(p.matcher("hellotxt").matches());  // false
```

Note that the string with just one dot, `"."` matches as well. To ensure that you have *some* characters in front and after the dot, you could change the `*` to `+`: `.+[.].+`.

---

The reason you get `PatternSyntaxException`:

The `*` operator is to be interpreted as "the previous character repeated zero or more times". Since you started your expression with `*` there was no character to repeat, thus an exception was thrown.

Answer (score 1):

The `*` character has a different meaning in regular expressions than when used on the command line as a file wildcard.  More information about the Java Pattern regular expression syntax can be found here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html

This will find the text you are looking to match:

```
Pattern.compile(".*\\..*");
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you meant:

```
Pattern.compile("\\*\\.\\*");
```

If not, and asterisk means 'any character' then

```
Pattern.compile(".*\\..*");
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to write:

```
Pattern.compile("\\*\\.\\*");
```

Because `*` has a special meaning (zero or more) in a regex. So you have to escape it with a `\\`.

Another way could be:

```
Pattern.compile("[*][.][*]");
```

because `*` loses its other significance when it appears between `[` and `]`.

If you want to parse a filename of format `*.*`, this should be enough:

```
Pattern.compile(".+\\..+");
```

To match any filename (which may or may not have an extension) you can use

```
Pattern.compile(".+(\\..+)?");
```

Answer (score 0):

If you mean, you wand to filter out files with a dot "." in its name, use this one:

```
Pattern.compile("[^\\.]*\\.[^\\.]*")
```

Comment: No need to escape the `.` in a character class.

Answer (score 0):

`Pattern.compile(".*\\/.*\\..*");` use this pattern.It will match all file names which are containing a dot. Asterisk is a special character. It means that the symbol coming before `*` can be 0 or more times. So you can't write it without character before.
For example for a file name `C:/folder.1/folder.2/file.txt` pattern will work so:
`.*` - `C:/folder.1/folder.2` (everything until finds the last `/` character)
`\/` - `/` character
`.*` - `file` (everything until finds the last `.` character (dot))
`\\.` - `.` (dot)
`.*` - `txt` (everything after `.` (actually the file extention))

Comment: invalid escape sequence (valid ones are  \b  \t  \n  \f  \r  \"  \'  \\ )

Comment: I just missed a \ for escaping / and edited my answer just now.

Comment: why would you want to escape `/` anyway?